# Angular2 ng-translate not importing

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on ng2-translate in my ionic2 app and following its [Github's](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) docs instructions.

However when I import "TranslateModule" 
`import {TranslateModule} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';`it gives me this error "Module my_node-module_path/ng2-translate/ng2-translate has no exported member TranslateModule."
And I have npm installed it.
Can anyone help me out here? Thanks.

**@NgModule Code **

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    FillForm,
    MainPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
     IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
     BrowserModule,
     HttpModule,
     TranslateModule.forRoot()
   ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    FillForm,
    MainPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: []
})
```

**File Structure**

[image]

Comment: Had you exports the `TranslateModule`?

Comment: @Poonam I  have already run npm install ng2-translate --save command...after this import should work but its not

Comment: Had you added this imported module with `@NgModule({ })`?

Comment: @Poonam updated ngModule code in question...pls take a look now

Comment: Ok, one more thing.. Had you updated your `SystemJS`?

Comment: I am not sure if I have any system.js file...I have updated file structore of my project in question....can you take a look at that and tell me if some file needs some update before importing TranslateModule. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125886/discussion-between-poonam-and-myke-11j).